# How to resolve an error in Typescript about `withStateHandlers`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components, recompose

I tried to make a React sample application using HOC.
but since I got an error in Typescript, I couldn't keep making anymore.

I got this error message below

```
(34,38): Type '{ timeLeft: number; timerId?: Timer | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'StateHandler<LStateProps>'.
  Type '{ timeLeft: number; timerId?: Timer | undefined; }' provides no match for the signature '(...payload: any[]): Partial<LStateProps> | undefined'.
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve it?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  compose,
  StateHandler,
  StateHandlerMap,
  withStateHandlers,
} from 'recompose';

import Timer, { TimerProps } from 'components/Timer';

interface LStateProps {
  timeLeft: number;
  timerId?: NodeJS.Timer;
}

type LStateHandlerProps = {
  reset: () => StateHandler<LStateProps>;
  tick: () => StateHandler<LStateProps>;
  setTimerId: (timerId: NodeJS.Timer) => StateHandler<LStateProps>;
} & StateHandlerMap<LStateProps>;

type EnhancedTimerProps = TimerProps & LStateProps & LStateHandlerProps;

const enhance = compose<EnhancedTimerProps, TimerProps>(
  withStateHandlers<LStateProps, LStateHandlerProps, TimerProps>(
    props => ({
      timeLeft: props.limit,
    }),
    {
      reset: (state, props) => () => ({
        ...state,
        timeLeft: props.limit,
      }),
      tick: (state, props) => () => ({
        ...state,
        timeLeft: state.timeLeft - 1,
      }),
      setTimerId: (state, props) => (timerId: NodeJS.Timer) => ({
        ...state,
        timerId,
      }),
    },
  ),
);

export default enhance(Timer as React.SFC<EnhancedTimerProps>);
```

Comment: "I could keep making anymore". ???? Huh?

Comment: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstatehandlers

Comment: 1) If you right click on StateHandler in the import and select go to definition- does it take you to code in your IDE? 2) What version of recompose are you using?

Comment: I don't confess to know much about React. But from the sound of it maybe LStateProps should extend some interface in StateHandler. See these threads. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19212  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to simply change your type `LStateHandlerProps` like this

```
type LStateHandlerProps = {
  reset: StateHandler<LStateProps>;
  tick: StateHandler<LStateParops>;
  setTimerId: StateHandler<LStateProps>;
} & StateHandlerMap<LStateProps>;
```

Explanation: if you hover your mouse to any handler of the state, you will see the type of the function like this

```
reset(state: LStateProps, props: TimerProps): () => StateHandler<LStateProps>
```

and the problem with this type is that the definition of `StateHandler<LStateProps>` is a function

```
type StateHandler<TState> = (...payload: any[]) => Partial<TState> | undefined;
```

So it means that the type of `reset` function is not double arrow, but instead - triple arrow that is not matching your function ex

```
 reset: (state, props) => () => ({
     ...state,
     timeLeft: props.limit,
 })
```